# Anybody or somebody? Don't or doesn't?

Tags: some-any, do

I'm trying to write this parable:

> Just as knowledge alone of a language doesn't make somebody a poet...

Questions:

- Does one write "doesn't" or "don't"? From what I know of grammar, I would go with "doesn't", but it doesn't sound right.
- "somebody" or "anybody"? Which one is correct in this case? My intended meaning is "a given person".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say it doesn't sound right.

> Just as knowledge alone of a language doesn't make ...

[Just as] knowledge [alone of a language] doesn't make somebody a poet...

knowledge doesn't make somebody a poet...

---

"anybody" in that sentence is much more emphatic.

Comment: I don't have a native ear, that's all ;-) . Thanks!

Comment: I upvoted this answer. That makes three down-votes. I'm curious also. Why?

Comment: I can't speak to the DV, chasly, but doesn't, *Just as knowledge of  language alone, doesn't make someone/anyone a poet*, sound less awkward?

Comment: @dsign Thanks for the info. Some of my votes have been going up and down like a yoyo. I think a couple of people have been downvoting all my answers, no matter what they are. I believe the system can detect such users. I just put a query on meta about it.

Comment: @LittleEva It is actually used in a context where the presence of more than one language is implied/discussed. But otherwise I would go with your suggestion.

Comment: @LittleEva - Thanks for your comment. Sometimes I wish this was a forum so we could have discussions about these things! I can't see a need for an extra comma. Could you explain?

Comment: Ignore the comma (I often *trip* on them), what I meant was that 'just as knowledge alone of language' reads rather awkwardly to me, and moving 'alone' to after 'knowledge of language' (again, to me) seems to read better. Also IMO, 'someone/anyone' reads easier than 'somebody/anybody'. Original is certainly grammatically acceptable, so it's really just a matter of taste. And, just so you know (and can feel comfortable with me), I wouldn't DV anyone because of a difference in style or opinion. Down-votes should be reserved for answers that are demonstrably wrong, and therefore unhelpful. :-)

Comment: @LittleEva but it's *knowledge alone of* **a** *language.*

Comment: @phoog - it doesn't **need** to be singular, though. In fact, dsign says, in comment here, *It is actually used in a context where the presence of* **more than one language** *is implied/discussed*.

Answer (score 3):

It should correctly be written ***doesn't***, as *knowledge*- its subject - is third person singular. Only for a third person plural subject, or a first person singular, would one write *don't* e.g. *they don't know* or *I don't know*.

Either ***somebody*** or ***anybody*** could be used. The sentence would mean almost exactly the same thing, but *anybody* would be more insistent, or assertive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't;
Thou doesn't;
* He or she doesn't;
We don't;
You don't;
They don't

In your poem, * Knowledge looks like a third person singular noun to me so:

Knowledge doesn't

Comment: The second-person singular should be *thou dost not*. I have no idea how it might be shortened - I have never seen it thus.

Comment: @WS2 I believe it's *thou dostn't*: https://www.google.com/#q=dostn%27t

Comment: Yes I too paused on the second person singular. The other persons are all abbreviations and I believe the shortening of thou dost not is thou doesn't just as in he doesn't is the shortening of he does not. I too have never (well, almost never) seen  thou doesn't, but that is merely because any thou construct is archaic rather than because it is wrong. WS2's dostn't seems preferable.

Comment: @Anton no. I've never claimed to know what the shortened form is.